# Precursors quest: Where is my 6th artifact?

Tags: stellaris

I got a quest in my situation log where I need to investigate 6 artifacts. Unfortunately I only got 5 of them which I all investigated:
[image: Situation Log]

Is that a bug? Or do I need to do something for the 6th to appear on the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/50so9m/is_it_just_me_or_are_the_precursor_events_really/) **it is possible to find 6 artifacts**, but it is extremely hard.

> Due to the way anomaly spawns, it's extremely hard to find 6 precursor artifacts (there are 12 in total and yes AI can stop you from finishing)

A **"solution"** to make it easier is to manipulate the gamefiles:

> Go to Stellaris\common\anomalies\00_anomalies.txt 
>   and from line 
>   Vultaum Precursor Discoveries 
>   to line 
>    EVENT SPAWNED DISCOVERIES 
>   do following: 
>    within each anomaly = { } scope directly under 
>   "category=???", add new "weight" or replace existing ones value, 
>  
>   like this: 
>    weight = 5000 
>   there ought to be 76 of them.

(This "solution" is also from the Reddit-post mentioned above.)

Comment: So my AI opponents likely snatched them and now none of us can finish that quest? What a poor design choice. But thank you for the answer.

Comment: Update 1.4 "Kennedy" added a lot of new events that spawn additional Precursor anomalies to deal with exactly this situation. I don't know how rare they are but you should get one eventually.

Comment: @PaulZ I think I might have receives such an event. It told me something was strange about some random moon. But nothing showed up in the situation log, that moon was already surveyed (the whole galaxy is) and my science ships had no special option when being sent there.

Comment: Prior to that last update, I had only finished this quest once. It's definitely more doable now, although sometimes I end up investigating anomalies for multiple other precursor empires before I finally find the last one for the empire whose quest I have.